# Plotly legend doesn't scale on phone

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm making a plotly plot using Dash. When I view it on my desktop it looks good
[image: Desktop]

But when I view it on my phone, the legend position overlaps the graph.
[image: Phone]

My legend is set up using

```
legend=dict(
    bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    orientation="h",
    yanchor="bottom",
    y=-0.15,
    xanchor="left",
    x=0
)
```

How do I fix the legend?
Bonus question, how do I fix the modebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a hacky workaround. The reason for the scaling issue was the screen width on phones is very low (~300px), so I set the min-width of the body to 500px

```
body {
    min-width:500px;
}
```

This causes the site to appear zoomed in after first loading it, so I put in the small JS script

```
<meta id="myViewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        if(window.innerWidth <= 500) {
            var mvp = document.getElementById('myViewport');
            mvp.setAttribute('content','width=500');
        }
    }
</script>
```

This seems to improve it to the point of useability. Not a perfect solution, but eh.. I also had a locked aspect ratio before, but I have unlocked the aspect ratio for phones so it's free to flex.

[image: Result]